Pintura Image Editor For Expo React Native Project
Is it posibble to use Pintura Image Editor inside Expo React Native Project, if so, how to install and setup the same? I read that is necessary to use WebView, is it? If this way depends on WebView can somebody give me example of it?
I wasn't able to integrated it
